# Receving large data from webservice in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, soap, nsdata

In my iphone application i have to recieve 1000 images from webmethod . It will take too long time. 
Instead of waiting that muc time is there any process to get data from service by part by part.
Is there any possiblity let help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about lazy loading image views?

Comment: Thanks for response sir                                          What i mean that i have to retrive large data from webservice it will take too much time. Instead of waiting to get all data can i show some data which i recieved. For example in YOUTUBE when vedio is running it will buuffering and display data. I am looking like that I have to got data and show and data processing is continued.

Comment: @KAREEMMAHAMMED What Till said was correct.. Please have a look into lazy loading..

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. I'm sure it will help what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do It. I've already implemented that using **`AsyncImageView`** which is inherited from **`UIImageView`**. What it does is it stores images in Cache memory fetched from a url and whenever you need to load image from the **same** URL again it will simply load it from the cache memory saving a lots of time.

Just follow the link for implementing that:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView#readme

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

**Update 1:**

Please have a look at the image showing the technique I've implemented it lets you do other activity while images are loading.:

[image]

Comment: If you do not understand this method feel free to ask i'll be pleased to help you out.

Comment: Yes thanks for response sir. But actually exactly i am looking for not only image i have to retrive data from webservice it will contains images and more associated information with that. I have to show data which i have gained and process is need to be continued

Comment: Images are the things which will consume all of the time in loading. So if you make image loading like this it'll help you somewhat..